# Integer equals method

Tags: java, hashcode

Normally when you have an object an objects Equals methods is equal to another object of same type if the two hashcodes are alike.

Does Integer work the same way by comparing hashcodes or does it work in a different way?

Comment: OpenJDK compares the integer values: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java

Comment: Why is it important for you?

Comment: @AleksanderGralak im a nerd!

Comment: @Marc why don't your wear your hat?

Comment: @gresdiplitude haha cant make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two objects that have the same hashcode need not be `equals()`.

Two objects that are `equals()` must have the same hashcode.

This basically means you may have (occasional) hashcode collisions.

The `Integer` `equals()` method simply compares the `int` value it wraps with the other `Integer`'s `int` value. Hashcodes don't come into it.

Note that the `equals()` and `hashcode` aggrement is not strictly *required*, but it is relied upon by the numerous JDK classes that use an internal `Hashtable`, eg the various `java.util.Hashxxx` classes.

Comment: @Boemian but  if the metod equals considers two objects equal, hashcode must be the same value for both objects

Comment: @MarcRasmussen That's exactly what I've said. I've re-worded my answer to make it clearer

Answer (score 4):

If you check the source of the Integer.java wrapper class, you can find that the equals method has been overridden to check that both the Integer objects have same int value.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (obj instanceof Integer) {
           return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
       }
       return false;
}
```

So you can say JDK compares the integer values inside the object.

Comment: Just one correction. java.lang.Integer does not inherit from Object. So the equals method is not an overridden method. It's just a member method.

Comment: @Raheel You might need to check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html).

Comment: Looks like java.lang.Integer inherits from Number which inherits from Object. I thought the whole point of java.lang.Integer is that it is an Object.

Answer (score 2):

Integer equals() method compares int values as `==` operator does, See below code of `Integer.equals()` method.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   if (obj instanceof Integer) {
      return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why is it important to you?

`Integer#equals` checks if two int values are equal, and not just references. So the actual `Integer` objects might be different (different references), however be equivalent.